# This layout or it's parent layout is possibly useless (AnDroid)

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to use more than one `CheckBox` in each tab, but only one box shows up in the tab even though I have three under LinearLayout.

I set the ID for each checkbox also.

Here is the code that is being used.

main.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/widget43"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:orientation="vertical"
             >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/root"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Tortillas" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/root1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Tortillas1" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/roo2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Tortillas2" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: How did this compile? The LinearLayout has no height attribute.

Comment: @ZedScio is that the only thing I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: How come only one checkbox shows up in the tab?

Comment: Please show the stacktrace from your LogCat.

Comment: Set the height of the LinearLayout and and orientation="vertical"

Comment: Thanks guys. Now I have another problem. (Please see edited question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Barak, you are missing a linear layout after TabHost

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/widget43"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/root"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tortillas" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/root1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tortillas1" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/roo2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tortillas2" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the CheckBox width and height to "wrap_content" instead of "fill_parent".  The first one fills the parent and there's nothing left for the rest.

**EDIT**

Change the heightof the LinearLayout to wrap_content as well (looking at some of my own, that's how I have them set up).

Comment: I did that, but then the checkbox appears on TOP of the tab.